# C++ general tree iterator - backward paths

Tags: c++, tree, iterator, traversal

I'd like to define an iterator over a general tree. Here is an example(from wikipedia) of binary one:

[image]

Iterator should allow me to traverse this tree structure in pre-order. I can easily achieve that using std::stack (get the Node from stack, set as current one, add it's children to the stack).

But I wish I get also nodes, which are on the "backward".

Nodes at example picture should be visited in a following order:
F, B, A, B*, D, C, D*, E, D*, B*, F*, G, I, H

'*' - means that node is visited in a backward.

Iterator should also store information if it is a "normal" visit, or backward one.

Which approach would you take to handle that?

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are having. If you keep a stack of currently visited nodes you can push and pop as you like. What have you tried?

Comment: are you saying that your iterator needs to visit every non-leaf node more than once ? If so, why ? If not, then what's wrong with the common iterative pre-order tree traversal algorithm(s) ?

Comment: @Peter Wood How can I distinguish if the node I took from the stack is visited the second time?

Comment: @Sander De Dycker Yes. Every non-leaf node will be visited more then once.

Comment: May I ask why you want this ?

Comment: you can define a property for each nodes to decide you have visited it or not.

Comment: @Dejwi you can distinguish by looking that the stack operation is pop or push. if you are poping the node from stack it means you got it second time othervise evry push operation means that you are dealing with that node first time

Comment: @abidinberkay I will rethink this idea. Actually I visit the node first time when I pop it ;). What about visiting it third time then?

Comment: @Sander De Dycker because before I go to the D state from A state I need to go back to the B state.

Comment: I understand that's how you envision pre-order traversal in your head, but I meant : why "visit" it more than once, where "visit" means to return it from your iterator, rather than a hidden implementation detail.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker Ok, I wasn't clear enough. The outer algorithms need to know "the path" and knew when we go backward.